# How can I add more than one data type with @ApiModelProperty

Tags: spring-boot, annotations, swagger, springfox

I have a property that can either be defined as a double or string.
How can I define this with `@ApiModelProperty`?
In YAML, I'd go:

```
properties:
    valueA:
    type: object
    additionalProperties:
        type: ["double", "string"]
```

The code I got is the following:

```
@ApiModelProperty(value="The value can either be a double or a string.", 
                  example = "0.5", dataType = "java.lang.Double")
private Object valueA;
```

It seems that I can't add two `@ApiModelProperty` per value or add two `dataType` attributes. How can I define that this value can be set as either a double or string?

Comment: `type: [double, string]` is not valid in OpenAPI, you need `oneOf` as in `oneOf: [{"type": "double"}, {"type": "string"}]`. Note that `oneOf` is supported in OpenAPI 3.0 but not in OpenAPI 2.0. I think you'll need Swagger Core 2.X to make use of that.

Comment: Thanks Helen, but then how could I turn `oneOf` into annotation?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Springfox annotations, sorry. Actually it looks like Springfox [does not support OpenAPI 3.0](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2022) yet.